# How to get the data per month in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the data per every month.

I'm a newbie at `MySQL`.

I just google and learn from the internet.

So, My Query may be not suitable.

If not suitable, please fix my query.

**HERE IS MY QUERY**

```
SELECT
  SUM( cr_dt > EXTRACT( YEAR_MONTH FROM CURDATE() ) 
         AND 
       cr_dt < EXTRACT( YEAR_MONTH FROM CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH )
     ) as thisMonth, 
  SUM( cr_dt > EXTRACT( YEAR_MONTH FROM CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
         AND
       cr_dt < EXTRACT( YAER_MONTH FROM CURDATE()
     ) as last1Month
FROM MYTABLE
```

I just found the `EXTRACT()` and `INTERVAL`, but I don't know it may suitable.

If you have a better way to solve, share please.

**WHAT I EXPECT**

```
| thisMonth | last1Month | 
+-----------+------------+
|  123      |  1294      |
```

**WHAT I SEE NOW**

```
| thisMonth | last1Month | 
+-----------+------------+
|  0        |  0         |
```

**SAMPLE DATAS**

```
| idx |        cr_dt        |
+-----+---------------------+
| 1   | 2018-02-01 17:00:00 |
| 2   | 2018-02-19 16:00:00 |
| 3   | 2018-02-28 15:00:00 |
| 4   | 2018-03-04 14:00:00 |
| 5   | 2018-04-01 13:00:00 |
| 6   | 2018-04-09 12:00:00 |
| 7   | 2018-04-12 11:00:00 |
| 8   | 2018-04-17 10:00:00 |
```

Comment: Read up on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html and please add sample data as text to your question.

Comment: @P.Salmon I add sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use conditional aggregation here, something like this:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN cr_dt >= DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%Y/%m/01')
               THEN 1 END) AS thisMonth,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN cr_dt >= DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y/%m/01') AND 
        cr_dt < DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%Y/%m/01') THEN 1 END) AS last1Month
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE cr_dt >= DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y/%m/01');
```

More typically you might see this sort of query using a `GROUP BY` clause, to compute aggregates over individual groups.  In your case, however, it appears you want to aggregate over the entire table.

Comment: You should add a (WHERE) condition which will ignore all rows before last month for better  performance.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel And, better yet, add an index on the `cr_dt` column, which would be usable both in that `WHERE` clause and in the counts.